# Should the predicate from a filtered index be in the front or back of the index?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2022

When creating a filtered index:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name ( column_list )
WHERE predicate;
```

It's my understanding you need to have the column(s) from the predicate also in your column list; but when I test this, I can't seem to spot any differences between the following designs (and a few other permutations of them).  The query analyser seems to pick the same index each time.

Scenario 1:  Predicate column in the front of the list of columns:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name ( predicateColumn, column_list )
WHERE predicate;
```

Scenario 2:  Predicate column at the end of the list of columns:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name ( column_list, predicateColumn )
WHERE predicate;
```

Scenario 3:  Predicate column in the included list of columns:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name ( column_list )
INCLUDE ( predicateColumn, column_list )
WHERE predicate;
```

Scenario 4:  Predicate column completely omitted:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name ( column_list )
INCLUDE ( column_list )
WHERE predicate;
```

I would have thought that Scenario 1 would be the correct one, but would appreciate any insights that could be shared.

My table that I'm testing on has a few hundred thousand records in it, so I would have imagined tht I'd at least see some kind of difference but they all seem to result in the same values.

I've done a lot of searching, and found questions around filtered indexes, but none that actually addresses this specific question.

**Closing summary**

Based on the feedback, I would personally lean towards scenario 1 or 3, depending on the use case.

- 3 will give you covering and negate a potential unneeded lookup.
- 1 will give you the above and also additional support if your predicate can
  differ from the statement that could be written.

I would personally lean towards using 1 as a generally recommended rule.

Comment: #4 makes most sense to me. Think of filtered index the same way as if sql server would take a snip from your table after applying there WHERE predicate and let you select from that snip

Comment: @siggemannen - there are sometimes issues with filtered indexes where the execution plan has a completely unneeded lookup back to the base table to lookup the columns and check something already guaranteed by the filtered index condition. https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/217046/3690

Comment: @MartinSmith that sounds vaguely familiar. But i guess what i described is the basic concept, which may or may not exactly match with cold harsh reality of query processing? I guess then it might make sense to include the filtered column

Comment: @siggemannen I agree with your observation on scenario 4, the only conclusion that I could come up with, was the SQL was actually including the predicate column(s) in the index & decision process, much like the clustered index columns get included regardless of whether they're specified?

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for the insights, that definitely does give me something to also consider.  Would scenario 1 make the most sense all things considered?

Comment: If you are only putting it into the index to get rid of unneeded key lookups then as an INCLUDE column would be best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217046/why-filtered-index-on-is-null-value-is-not-used) [are](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224149/should-the-filtering-columns-always-be-in-the-keys-includes) [certain](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/12/filtered-indexes-just-add-includes/) [circumstances](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/sql-plan/filtered-index-side-effect) when the compiler will use a filtered index, but still add an unnecessary predicate, and therefore if the column is ommitted completely then it could end up with an unnecessary Key Lookup.

If you just want to avoid that issue then adding to the `INCLUDE` is enough. There is no need to increase the index key size for that.

However, if your predicate covers multiple values (using `IN`) then you may want to add to the index key anyway. The exact key ordering would depend on what other predicates you have.

Comment: Thanks, this is gold!  I especially like this one: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/12/filtered-indexes-just-add-includes/

Comment: That one should have been kinda obvious to Erik: he says "It seemed insane to me that SQL would know the filter for the index is on (x > y), but wouldn’t use them even if (z > x)" but how could it if it doesn't have the actual value to test, only the fact that it's more than `y`? It can't infer anything in relation to `z` from that.

Comment: @Storm  We know that all rows `WHERE  u.Reputation > 500000` will definitely be in that filtered index with the `WHERE Reputation > 400000` predicate but it needs access to the column value to distinguish which rows were `> 500000` and should be returned and which were `> 400000 AND <= 500000` and should not be.